# python jsonify dictionary in utf-8

Tags: python, json, utf-8, flask

I want to get json data into utf-8

I have a list `my_list = []`

and then many appends unicode values to the list like this

```
my_list.append(u'ტესტ')

return jsonify(result=my_list)
```

and it gets

```
{
"result": [
"\u10e2\u10d4\u10e1\u10e2",
"\u10e2\u10dd\u10db\u10d0\u10e8\u10d5\u10d8\u10da\u10d8"
]
}
```

Comment: That's correct. Your data was encoded to JSON, with the unicode codepoints encoded to `\uabcd` escape points. What is the problem exactly? Because the encoding for the backslash characters, the `u` characters, etc. is the same in UTF8 and in ASCII, it may look confusing but it *is* legal JSON, *and* UTF8.

Comment: I also edited your question; you have a `list`, not a `dict`.

Comment: I want to get json as same values in utf-8 without unicode codepoints

Comment: You may want to make that explicit in your question, and do add *why* you need that. To a compliant JSON decoder there is no difference, by using escapes you avoid all sorts of problems; from proxies that cannot handle wide character data very well to missing character encoding information leading to decoding errors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the standard-library [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) instead, and set the `ensure_ascii` keyword parameter to False when encoding, or do the same with [`flask.json.dumps()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.json.dumps):

```
>>> data = u'\u10e2\u10d4\u10e1\u10e2'
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(data)
'"\\u10e2\\u10d4\\u10e1\\u10e2"'
>>> json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
u'"\u10e2\u10d4\u10e1\u10e2"'
>>> print json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
"ტესტ"
>>> json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
'"\xe1\x83\xa2\xe1\x83\x94\xe1\x83\xa1\xe1\x83\xa2"'
```

Note that you still need to explicitly encode the result to UTF8 because the `dumps()` function returns a `unicode` object in that case.

You can make this the default (and use `jsonify()` again) by [setting `JSON_AS_ASCII` to False](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/config/#JSON_AS_ASCII) in your Flask app config.

**WARNING**: do not include untrusted data in JSON that is not ASCII-safe, and then interpolate into a HTML template or use in a JSONP API, as you can cause syntax errors or open a cross-site scripting vulnerability this way. That's because [JSON is not a strict subset of Javascript](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset), and when disabling ASCII-safe encoding the U+2028 and U+2029 separators will not be escaped to `\u2028` and `\u2029` sequences.

Comment: the output is totally different in py3.5

Comment: @Blauhirn: That's because there are material differences between Python 2 and Python 3. The OP here is using Python 2 (evident by the `u` string prefixes).

Comment: @Blauhirn: in Python 2, string objects with non-ASCII characters are echoed with *escapes*, to ensure that the value remains ASCII safe. In Python 3 the rules have been relaxed and you now Unicode printable characters are left in as literals. Thus you'll see `'"ტესტ"'` even without using `print()`. Use `print(ascii(....))` if you want to see the Python 2 style.

Answer (score 110):

Use the following config to add UTF-8 support:

```
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```

Comment: You saved me to change my jsonify function with the json.dumps(). thanks...

Comment: Yeah, best solution if you also want to preserve indentation which jsonify adds, but json.dumps not.

Comment: Warning: [JSON is not a Javascript subset](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset), and disabling ASCII-safe encoding opens the door for issues with U+2028 and U+2029 separators in the data to break Javascript interpolation or JSONP APIs. This *could* leave you open to a cross-site scripting issue, depending on how the error is handled.

Comment: The best solution.

Comment: The best solution ever, after spent more than 1 hour to find a solution to handle non-Ascii characters. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Update: [JSON_AS_ASCII](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/#JSON_AS_ASCII) is deprecated since version 2.2, set `app.json.ensure_ascii` instead.

Answer (score 9):

If you still want to user flask's json and ensure the utf-8 encoding then you can do something like this:

```
from flask import json,Response
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(u'ტესტ')
    data = { "result" : my_list}
    json_string = json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii = False)
    #creating a Response object to set the content type and the encoding
    response = Response(json_string,content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8" )
    return response
```

#I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

> Changed in version 2.3: JSON_AS_ASCII, JSON_SORT_KEYS,
> JSONIFY_MIMETYPE, and JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR were removed. The
> default app.json provider has equivalent attributes instead.

Now we can change this behaviour like this:

```
from flask import json

json.provider.DefaultJSONProvider.ensure_ascii = False
```

Answer (score 2):

"The 'JSON_AS_ASCII' config key is deprecated and will"
" be removed in Flask 2.3. Set 'app.json.ensure_ascii'"
" instead."

Comment: app.json.ensure_ascii = False

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above solution was not sufficient. (Running flask on the GCP App Engine flexible environment). I ended up doing:

```
json_str = json.dumps(myDict, ensure_ascii = False, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
encoding = chardet.detect(json_str)['encoding']
json_unicode = json_str.decode(encoding)
json_utf8 = json_unicode.encode('utf-8')
response = make_response(json_utf8)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
response.headers['mimetype'] = 'application/json'
response.status_code = status
```