# How to serialize cyrillic symbols to return in Flask?

Tags: python, json, flask, serialization, encoding

I have a problem with serialization in returning some json-formatted text.

```
from flask import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False


@app.route("/task", methods=['GET'])
def get_task():
    vals = {"value": "Привет!"}
    return jsonify(vals)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and when I test my endpoint my get request is:

```
import requests
requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/task")
```

and in response I got:

```
b'{"value":"\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!"}\n'
```

As you can see I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853694/python-jsonify-dictionary-in-utf-8), have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794623/how-to-correctly-produce-and-consume-utf-8-json-in-python3-with-flask-and-requ) - but in my case I need to get already encoded text, so that when I print the results - I can see the string - "Привет!". I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378441/does-flask-jsonify-support-utf-8), but it now just returns the output that I've attached.
So, overall, what I need is to get in response **already** utf-encoded text, so that when I print it in stdout I can see cyrillic symbols like this:

```
{'value': 'Привет!'}
```

Comment: What's wrong on `b'{"value":"\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!"}\n'.decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: In your case: `response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/task"); response.content.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @JosefZ yes, nothing wrong with that, it works. But I just want it already decoded.

Comment: Check whether `response.content.decode('utf-8') == response.text` returns `True` (I think so…)